# Why aren't my conditional compilation symbols working when I dotnet publish my .NET Core 3 project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish

I have a project which is targeting .NET Core 3. This project builds and runs fine in both Debug and Release configurations. Both configurations have a **Conditional compilation symbol** set in Visual Studio of `Glue`.

[image]

The resulting .csproj has the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;GLUE</DefineConstants>
  <OutputPath></OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;GLUE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As I mentioned earlier, if I run through Visual Studio, all works fine.

If I publish my app through the command line interface, the resulting app seems to ignore the conditional compilation symbol.

As a test, I added an #if around a section of code which will cause compile errors if the #if is excluded.

```
#if GLUE
        public MainGlueWindow()
        {
#endif
            mSelf = this;

            ...
```

If the GLUE conditional compilation symbol is considered, the code should compile fine, but I do get errors when I perform a `dotnet publish`. The full command I am using is:

`dotnet publish GlueFormsCore.csproj -r win-x86 -c Debug`

The error suggests the constructor header is missing:

`C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\FlatRedBall\FRBDK\Glue\Glue\MainGlueWindow.cs(95,19): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration [C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\FlatRedBall\FRBDK\Glue\Glue\GlueFormsCore_tksugttl_wpftmp.csproj]`

I should point out that `x86` is the only platform in my csproj.

I don't know if the problem is caused by the absence of specifying x86 as the platform, but if so I don't know how to specify that on the dotnet publish command.

Can anyone tell me why the dotnet publish command is not considering the GLUE conditional compilation symbol?

### Update 1

I was able to solve the problem by removing the Platform from the csproj PropertyGroup condition, as shown in the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;GLUE</DefineConstants>
    <OutputPath></OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;GLUE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

While this does confirm that the problem is related to the platform, I'm not sure how to specify the platform when building. This is unfortunately not a final solution for me because other projects rely on the platform and I cannot remove that from all configurations.

Comment: Could you use something like `dotnet publish GlueFormsCore.csproj -r win-x86 -c Debug /p:DefineConstants="GLUE"`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to make a difference - appending `/p:DefineConstants="Glue"` did not solve the compile errors caused by the `#if GLUE` test

Comment: You do realize they are case sensitive, correct?

Comment: Yes my apologies, I did actually use all caps GLUE in my command line: `dotnet publish GlueFormsCore.csproj -r win-x86 -c Debug /p:DefineConstants="GLUE"`

Comment: I had this same problem on a build machine (not when run locally). It only occurred in certain contexts, seemed unreliable. I suspect it's a bug frankly.